# Firebase counter, bulking updates cases

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

We know that Firebase does not have a count query, the methods to have a counter are two, get all data in the client side or store a count value in the database. I use this second method because the first is valid only when there are few data.

The problem with this method is that I can have many concurrent writers, I solved this problem with my method that if a data is not stored it tries to re-save the data with incremented or decremented counter.

OK this method worked well when I want to change only one counter, but in different cases I want to change many different counters with one transaction and in this mode there is a risk that after different attempts the data could not be saved, because we can have many concurrent writers in many different nodes. An example of data structure with an atomic updates is as below:

If I save this

```
"comment": {
   "counter": {},
   "Data": {
      "$Comment":{}
   }
}


comment/counter = val + 1
comment/Data/comment1 = data
```

it works if I fail to update because other writer is updating the counter just when I can retry with a new counter value and usually after the first time I conclude the operation with success, but for example, if I want to delete a user and all his actions, I want to store this type of data

```
"comment":{
  "counter":{},
  "Data": {
    "$Comment":{}
  }
},

"$user": {
  "follower":{
    "counter":{},
    "data":{
      "$Follower": {}
    }
  }
}
comment/counter = val - 1
comment/Data/comment2 = null
user1/follower/counter = val - 1
user1/follower/data/user30 = null
user2/follower/counter = val - 1
user2/follower/data/user30 = null
user3/follower/counter = val - 1
user3/follower/data/user30 = null
```

is visible that in case of a bulk update, I must update a lot of counters that can have a lot of concurrent writers and in this case it is very easy that it is impossible to be able to update all the counters  after different retries.

another case is this

```
"photo":{
  "$photo":{
    "comment":{
      "counter":{},
      "Data": {
        "$Comment":{}
      }
   }
}

photo/10/comment/counter = val - 1
photo/10/comment/Data/comment1 = null
photo/10/comment/counter = val - 1
photo/10/comment/Data/comment2 = null
photo/10/comment/counter = val - 1
photo/10/comment/Data/comment3 = null
```

In this case, it is impossible to update the counter because I try to delete different comments with same counter that can be equal only for value + 1 or for value - 1. If I want to delete all user data, it is possible that he write some comments in the same photo but can't I  delete all of this comments in one transaction because the counter can be updated only with single transaction.

I see a lot of such complications only because not exist a count query that exist in any type of database (sql or nosql). I do not understand why. This involves a lot of problems otherwise solvable without wasting time

below is my javascript function to update a counter. It is a recursive function that recall herself if fail the update because of others concurrent writers

```
this.singleUpdate = function (paths, increment, countPath, retryCounter, callback) {
            firebase.database().ref(countPath).once('value', function (counter) {
                var value = counter.val() ? counter.val().value : 0;
                var countValue = increment ? value + 1 : value - 1;
                paths[countPath] = { value: null };                

                if (!increment && countValue == 0) { paths[countPath] = null; }
                else {
                    paths[countPath].value = countValue;                    
                }

                firebase.database().ref().update(paths, function (error) {
                    if (error) {
                        retryCounter++;
                        if (retryCounter < 3) { singleUpdate(paths, increment, countPath, retryCounter, callback); }
                        else { callback(false, error); }
                    } else {
                        return callback(true, countValue);
                    }
                });
            });
        }
```

Comment: Is this a question? If so, can you provide a code example that demonstrates the issue and a snippet of your Firebase structure (as text please, no images) so we can understand your data?

Comment: i post my function for update the counter, but the problem is not in the client code but in the firebase data structure, if i want to update some different counters probably i fail my transaction because more counter mean more possible concurrent writers. but in firebase not exist a count query this is the unique method possible i think

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions), aren't you?

> When working with data that could be corrupted by concurrent
>   modifications, such as incremental counters, you can use a transaction
>   operation. You can give this operation an update function and an
>   optional completion callback. The update function takes the current
>   state of the data as an argument and returns the new desired state you
>   would like to write. If another client writes to the location before
>   your new value is successfully written, your update function is called
>   again with the new current value, and the write is retried.

Example from docs:

```
function toggleStar(postRef, uid) {
  postRef.transaction(function(post) {
    if (post) {
      if (post.stars && post.stars[uid]) {
        post.starCount--;
        post.stars[uid] = null;
      } else {
        post.starCount++;
        if (!post.stars) {
          post.stars = {};
        }
        post.stars[uid] = true;
      }
    }
    return post;
  });
}
```

As an addition, you can delete only content posted by deleted user, so counters will remain with same value and instead of comment/post there will be "Post was deleted"

Comment: yes i know transaction.  another thing is that i want to update more counter with only one query, in this case i not can use transaction but the update method. the problem is that are all client side methods i think that firebase needs increment and decrement methods that work in the server side. otherwise with a lot of users is easy to fail the writing for different times.

Comment: @DThink do you have separate app server? I could provide you with example in Go or Python to implement what you want. But Firebase has only transaction

Comment: for the bulk update i use a nodejs script but the method is the same, transaction or update. but He does not respond to my needs :/